# Monty Hall JS Implementation is giving 50/50 output

Tags: javascript, math

Apparently my simulation is wrong, but I cannot wrap my head around why. It gives an output of 50/50 where it should be clearly 66/33. I've reviewed my code for 2 days now and still can't find it.

I even looked at some reference trying to understand how their code works: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem

I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

there is a github page where it runs: https://dupuqub.github.io/testes/monty.html

```js
    const roll = (a, b) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1))
    const sample = 100000
    let yes = 0
    let no = 0
    
    for(i = sample; i > 0; i --){
    
     const doors = ["a","b","c"]
    
        // where the car will be found.
     const car = roll(0,2)
    
        // the fictional player first selected door. 
     const first = roll(0,2)
    
        // the doors that weren't selected.
     const other_doors = doors.filter((door, index) => index !== first)
    
        // the door that is open to show there is no car there.
     const shown = roll(0,1)
    
        // if the player changed or not his mind.
     const change = roll(0,1)
    
        // the player's final decision.
     const final = change ? other_doors[shown ? 0 : 1] : doors[first]
    
        // if the player won or not.
     const winner = doors[car] === final
    
        // if the player WON:
        // give a point to YES if there was a change.
        // give a point to NO if there wasn't a change.
     if(winner) change ? yes ++ : no ++
    }
    
    console.log(sample)
    console.log("CHANGED and won: " + yes)
    console.log("DID NOT CHANGE and won: " + no)
```

Comment: 1) The `shown` door is only selected randomly if the player did select the car, otherwise he might "accidentally" get shown the car 2) the strategy whether to change or not should not be determined randomly - you should do one run with a "keep" strategy and one with a "change" strategy to evaluate their respective outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked your code and got it working. I believe the main mistake is that the door that is opened can only be a door that the user not only didn't already pick but also where we know the car isn't.

```js
const roll = (a, b) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1))
const sample = 100000
let yes = 0
let no = 0

for(i = sample; i > 0; i --){

    const doors = ["a","b","c"]

    // the door where the car is
    const car = doors[roll(0, 2)]

    // the fictional player's first selected door
    const first = doors[roll(0, 2)]

    // the doors that weren't selected
    const other_doors = doors.filter(door => door !== first)

    // the doors that can be shown where there is no car
    const showable = other_doors.filter(door => door !== car)

    // the door that is opened to show there is no car there.
    const shown = showable[roll(0, showable.length - 1)]

    // the door that was not first selected and was not opened
    const closed = doors.filter(door => door !== first && door !== shown)[0];

    // the first door the fictional player selected and the remaining closed door.
    const final_doors = [first, closed]

    // if the player changed or not his mind.
    const change = roll(0, 1)

    // the player's final decision.
    const final = change ? closed : first

    // if the player won or not.
    const winner = car === final

    // if the player WON, give a point to YES if there was a change or to NO if there wasn't a change.
    if(winner) change ? yes ++ : no ++
}

console.log(sample)
console.log("CHANGED and won: " + yes)
console.log("DID NOT CHANGE and won: " + no)
```